# How to combine n observables dynamically into a list?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a collection of observables that generate state changes for a so-called `Channel`. And I have a `ChannelSet` that should monitor those channels.

I would like to write something like this: if one channel is operational, the channel set is up, else, the channel set is down.

```
IEnumerable<ChannelState> channelStates = ...;
if (channelStates.Any(cs => cs == ChannelState.Operational))
    channelSet.ChannelSetState = ChannelSetState.Up;
else
    channelSet.ChannelSetState = ChannelSetState.Down;
```

But where do I get my `IEnumerable<ChannelState>`? If I have 1 channel, I can simply subscribe to its state changes and modify the state of the channel set accordingly. For two channels, I could use `CombineLatest`:

```
Observable.CombineLatest(channel0States, channel1States, (cs0, cs1) =>
    {
        if (cs0 == ChannelSetState.Up || cs1 == ChannelSetState.Up)
            return ChannelSetState.Up;
        else
            return ChannelSetState.Down;
    });
```

But I have an `IEnumerable<Channel>` and a corresponding `IEnumerable<IObservable<ChannelState>>`. I'm looking for something like `CombineLatest` that is not limited to a fixed number of observables.

To complicate matters, the collection of channels can be added to and removed from. So once in a while, a channel will be added for example. The new channel also generates state changes that need to be incorporated.

So what I'm actually looking for is a function:

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<ChannelState>> --> IObservable<ChannelSetState>
```

that keeps up-to-date when the input changes. There should be some way to accomplish this using Rx but I can't really figure out how.

Comment: Can you add details on how new Channels are created?

Comment: Seems like in this case you need a combination of CombineLatest some sort of Accumulator. I have this problem all of the time with things like Validation (where all objects need to be valid at the same time for the composite validation to be valid). This is a great question.

Comment: @Scott What do you want to know about channel creation? They are rather complex objects that wrap a TCP connection.

Comment: @Anderson Thanks. I have come up with a solution that I'll post tomorrow. Not entirely satisfied because I think a more elegant solution should be possible.

Comment: Don't need to know the insides of the Channel ctors, but what the use case is for when/how they are created. Basically, can we start w/ an `Observable<Channel>` and solve from that point?

Comment: I see what you mean. When starting with an `IObservable<Channel>`, channels can be added dynamically. However, I'm not sure how removing should work then. Going to check out Enigmativity's answer now to see if he has a solution for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Anderson I think Enigmativity's answer matches your problem. If you have observables that generate binary states (e.g. valid/invalid) it's a very nice solution.

Comment: @Ronald Wildenberg: I'll give it a try. Something about ignoring the enumerable of channelstate sources makes me think this isn't appropriate. If any one of the sources is `false` at any given time, the whole thing should be `false`... making each source indistinct using Merge seems like it wouldn't work, but I'll reserve judgement until after I test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fairly straight forward way to do what you want with Rx, but you need to think in terms of observables only and not mix in enumerables.

The function signature that you really need to think in terms of is:

```
IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>> --> IObservable<ChannelSetState>
```

Here's the function:

```
Func<IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>>, IObservable<ChannelSetState>> f =
    channelStates =>
        channelStates
            .Merge()
            .Select(cs => cs == ChannelState.Operational ? 1 : -1)
            .Scan(0, (cssn, csn) => cssn + csn)
            .Select(cssn => cssn > 0 ? ChannelSetState.Up : ChannelSetState.Down)
            .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

It is important that each `IObservable<ChannelState>` in the `IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>>` behaves properly for this to work.

I've assumed that the `ChannelState` enum has an `Idle` state and that each `IObservable<ChannelState>` will produce zero or more pairs of `Operational`/`Idle` values (`Operational` followed by `Idle`) before completing.

Also you said "the collection of channels can be added to and removed from" - thinking in terms of `IEnumerable<IObservable<ChannelState>>` this sounds reasonable - but in Rx you don't have to worry about removes because each observable can signal its own completion. Once it signals completion then it is as if it has been removed from the collection because it can not produce any further values. So you only need to worry about adding to the collection -  this is easy using subjects.

So now the function can be used like so:

```
var channelStatesSubject = new Subject<IObservable<ChannelState>>();
var channelStates = channelStatesSubject.AsObservable();
var channelSetStates = f(channelStates);

channelSetStates.Subscribe(css => { /* ChannelSetState subscription code */ });

channelStatesSubject.OnNext(/* IObservable<ChannelState> */);
channelStatesSubject.OnNext(/* IObservable<ChannelState> */);
channelStatesSubject.OnNext(/* IObservable<ChannelState> */);
// etc
```

I ran this using some test code, that used three random `ChannelState` observables, with a `Do` call in the `f` function for debugging, and got the following sequence:

```
1
Up
2
3
2
1
2
1
0
Down
1
Up
0
Down
```

I think that's what you're after. Let me know if I've missed anything.

---

As per the comments below, the `ChannelState` enum has multiple states, but only `Operational` means that the connection is up. So it's very easy to add a `DistinctUntilChanged` operator to hide multiple "down" states. Here's the code now:

```
Func<IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>>, IObservable<ChannelSetState>> f =
    channelStates =>
        channelStates
            .Merge()
            .Select(cs => cs == ChannelState.Operational ? 1 : -1)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Scan(0, (cssn, csn) => cssn + csn)
            .Select(cssn => cssn > 0 ? ChannelSetState.Up : ChannelSetState.Down)
            .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

---

Added code to ensure that the first select query always starts with a `1`. Here's the code now:

```
Func<IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>>, IObservable<ChannelSetState>> f =
    channelStates =>
        channelStates
            .Merge()
            .Select(cs => cs == ChannelState.Operational ? 1 : -1)
            .StartWith(1)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Scan(0, (cssn, csn) => cssn + csn)
            .Select(cssn => cssn > 0 ? ChannelSetState.Up : ChannelSetState.Down)
            .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It seems like everything I need is there. I hadn't realized that completing an IObservable<ChannelState> effectively means removing it from the 'list'. This is a lot better than the solution I came up with.

Comment: @Ronald - Completing on a `IObservable<ChannelState>` within a merged `IObservable<IObservable<ChannelState>>` effectively means it's removed from the list. Completing on a `IObservable<ChannelState>` by itself just means it won't produce any more values.

Comment: Hm, I still have one problem. My `IObservable<ChannelState>` is actually generated from a call to `Observable.FromEventPattern`. How do you complete such an observable?

Comment: And another problem: I actually have eight different channel states. So there is no sequence of (`Idle`/`Operational`) pairs in the event stream, which means that the `Scan` function scans for the wrong things. Not sure if that can be fixed in your solution. Because the event streams are merged, you lose some essential information: the channel that generated the event.

Comment: Not sure if this will work. Channels can cycle through a number of states, one of which is `Operational`.

Comment: @Ronald - The key thing here is that the channel goes into an operational state and then out of it before it can go back in. Of the eight states can you identify which are in and which are out? If so, my solution can still work.

Comment: @Ronald - The `FromEventPattern` should work fine. You can use the `TakeWhile` extension method to introduce a flag to stop the observable.

Comment: There is one state signaling an operational channel: `ChannelState.Operational`. All the other states (`Creating`, `Created`, `SettingUp`, ...) are an indication that the channel should not be used.

Comment: @Ronald - If `Operational` means `Up` and all others mean `Down` then my code still works.

Comment: If I cycle through `Creating` -> `Created` -> `SettingUp` -> `Operational` for one channel, the stream contains `-1,-1,-1,1`. The `Scan` operation than produces `-1,-2,-3,-2`. The final value, `-2`, doesn't lead to `ChannelSetState.Up`. Or maybe I have made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the update to your answer. Again a very elegant solution, thanks. I'll check if it now works as I want.

Comment: Still a problem :) If the first state is a down state, then you may never end up with a `cssn > 0`. This can be easily fixed though in the `Scan` function (never drop below `0`).

Comment: @Ronald - check out the query now. It solves the starting with -` issue.

Comment: @mtyson - What's a "Kant"?

Comment: Immanuel Kant, German philosopher with a reputation for extremely intelligent but dense writing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps start with an `IObservable<Channel>` rather than starting w/ `IEnumerable<Channel>`. A way to do this would be to use a `Subject<Channel>`, and when a new one is created, `OnNext()` it.

If you *need* a list,

xsChannels.Subscribe(item => 
{ 
    lock(list)
    {
        list.add(item);
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

I promised to add the solution I came up with myself, so here it is. As long as I haven't found anything better I'll use this, although I still think there has to be a better way :)

I use a class that uses a `ConcurrentDictionary` to keep the latest value from each registered observable. When an observable is unregistered, its latest value is removed again, as well as the subscription associated with it.

When any registered observable generates a value, all latest values are collected and sent to a `Subject`.

```
public class DynamicCombineLatest<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<IObservable<T>, T> _latestValues =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<IObservable<T>, T>();
    private readonly IDictionary<IObservable<T>, IDisposable> _subscriptions =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<IObservable<T>, IDisposable>();
    private readonly ISubject<IEnumerable<T>> _result =
        new Subject<IEnumerable<T>>();

    public void AddObservable(IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        var subscription =
            observable.Subscribe(t =>
                                 {
                                     _latestValues[observable] = t;
                                     _result.OnNext(_latestValues.Values);
                                 });
        _subscriptions[observable] = subscription;
    }

    public void RemoveObservable(IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        _subscriptions[observable].Dispose();
        _latestValues.Remove(observable);
        _subscriptions.Remove(observable);
    }

    public IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> Result
    {
        get { return _result; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid `Add` and `Remove` functions in the Rx world. Have your `Add` function return the `IDisposable` that will perform the remove. Then you don't need to have a `Remove` function and you can lose the `_subscriptions` dictionary.